# regasm.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to use a windows application on web, i found an article on that, im posting the link below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14276/Using-Windows-Application-on-web

In the above article im facing issue near the 10th step where it states that::
 "Now by using the "regasm.exe" create and place the CLSID of your dll in the registry
the exe file which is in the location "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\ "."

when i tried to access the regasm.exe from command prompt, im getting the errror as
"regasm.exe is not a valid win32 application"

how to resolve it?

Comment: With vs2010 installed, maybe you should look into "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe" or "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe"

Comment: yes i looked in to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe, that is what is giving error

Answer (score 0):

Re-install (repair) .NET framework 4 helped. (Found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de1b5f77-8171-42b5-b8a4-2cf5611d06cf/regasmexe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application?forum=netfxtoolsdev )